# Setting a Static Ip on Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, networking, server, network-manager, dns

I'm struggling with setting my static ip, nothing seems to work.

When I enter my interfaces, it says (by default):

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

And that's okay, so, now I just want to assign a static ip, and I am using the wlan0 device in order to do so, as eth0 is unavailable. I try to add in below, for example:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
 address 192.168.0.87/24
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 network 192.168.0.0
 broadcast 192.168.0.255
 gateway 192.168.0.1
 dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.87/24, 8.8.8.8
 wpa-ssid 'user'
 wpa-psk 'password' # I also tried it with hex value without quotation marks
```

For sure, I know that my gateway is like that, all of it comes from the interface settings under `nmcli dev list iface wlan0`, but then it does not work. When I reboot the system, despite my network manager is properly disabled, the connections do not work, it just freezes and times out every time.

What could possibly wrong here?

Comment: Address needs to be a single address, not a range. Leave out the _/24_, also applies to dns

Comment: Unless this is server (no GUI) you should consider setting your interface via the network-manager nm-applet GUI instead of modifying the /etc/network/interfaces file.

Comment: The fault was ultimately the matter or removing quotation marks from the username and putting a value in a hex way. Anyway, I took notes off from your hints and I'll improve my game. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Test this:

Open a terminal.

Run it:

```
sudo -i
nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Add the following lines for you wifi lan adaptor.

```
----------------------------------------------
# The wifi network interface
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.87
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.0.0
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    gateway 192.168.0.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1, 8.8.8.8
    wpa-ssid <Your wifi network SSID>
    wpa-psk <Your hex encoded wifi WPA password>
-----------------------------------------------
```

Control + O, save file. Control + X, close nano.

Answer (score 5):

Using the Network Manager GUI did the trick for me on Xubuntu 16.04:

Edit the wifi connection, and on IPv4 tab, enter:

- Method: Manual
- Address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (your static address,in this case: 192.168.1.128)
- Netmask: 24
- Gateway: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (your gateway address,in this case: 192.168.1.1)
- DNS Server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (your gateway address,in this case: 192.168.1.1)

---

Here's an example screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! While this is a good first answer, it can still be improved, with, say, a screenshot. If you feel like this is a good idea, please feel free to [edit] it into your answer. Otherwise, I'd recommend you read our [tour] and [answer] page in order to get a better idea of how this site works, and how to better keep providing awesome content!

Comment: how do you find your static and gateway address?

Comment: @ben432rew gateway is the ip of your router, and static is the address you chose (should be done through router first)

Answer (score 1):

To setting up a static IP in Ubuntu the proper way is:

Disable the graphical management of your network connection in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
Gather the information for the static IP (interface, IP to be used, default gateway, subnet, DNS)
Modify /etc/network/interfaces to include the information above.
Restart networking and network-manager services.

Comment: "These instructions assume you are using a wired ethernet port to set a static IP on..."